# SSH host key: Is the public one necessary and should the key be password protected

Tags: linux, ssh-host-key

I was playing around with my SSH server side config `sshd_config`. I replaced my default SSH host keys with only one RSA key while I'm using `Protocol 2` and key auth only.

```
ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -t rsa
```

This creates as expected two files

```
ssh_host_rsa_key
ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

While testing I found out it's not necessary to have the public key to establish a connection from the client.

1. When does the public key is necessary?
2. Furtheron I couldn't determine why it's necessary to have the private key password protected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q2. `sshd` *host* keys should *not* be password protected. If they are, `sshd` can't read them (unless you set up a host agent and preload it which is rare). This is because `sshd` is designed to run in background and cannot get the password(s) from the user, especially because it is usually started automatically at boot before any user is even logged-in. Instead the files for the `sshd` host key(s) should be secured against access by any userid other than the one which runs `sshd`, normally root, and that userid should be well protected and not used unnecessarily.

Q1. sshd does not need a separate `.pub` file because it can automatically compute the publickey from the privatekey. In contrast the *client* `ssh` (unless using an agent) usually wants to use the publickey for a userauth 'probe' *before* prompting for the password to actually use the privatekey, and this requires a separate `.pub` file except when using OpenSSH's 'new format' keyfile, which is required for Ed25519 since IIRC 6.5, and the default for *all* keys since 7.8 about a month ago. Since `ssh-keygen` doesn't know which you want, it always generates a `.pub` file, which does no harm if unneeded -- even if it is not secured, since it is public.